# Android flashing and tools for flashing

Tags: android

I want to know What is meant by flashing in android and what are the tools available  for flashing?

Comment: @casperOne I don't why you reported  not a real question.

Comment: Fails the fundamental test of "what have you tried"?

Comment: this is not a place to ask things other than coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link. [What is flashing](http://androidmobileaz.com/phone-repairs/muve-phone-cricket/what-is-flashing/)

The tools available for flashing in android is `fastboot` which is available with android-sdk

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Upvoted . Did you ever used fastboot ?

Comment: Yes. I've flashed several android handset. Answer upvoted but not accepted. If you think this is the correct answer for you, then accept it. This will help other people not to post same question again.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android Enthusiasts board](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc):

"Flashing means to copy or to install.... you are essentially wiping the device and restoring a previous state (a backup) or you are flashing a new ROM"

Fastboot is the tool typically used to flash. The Cyanogenmod wiki has a [great page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Fastboot) on when and how to use fastboot.

Answer (score 1):

Flashing is a term used in android to mark the reinstall(or fresh installing) of the OS on Android phones , ROM usually refers to pre-built images which are compatible with android phones, As mentioned Fastboot can be used for flashing, there are several websites and blog articles which show how to flash a custom ROM on android [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/05/08/complete-guide-how-to-flash-a-custom-rom-to-your-android-phone-with-rom-manager-full-backup-restore/) is one however you should probably go to xda developers or some other site to find more information on how to flash your particular android phones, it may be possible that you cannot flash your phone if bootloader is locked.